# PHP in Windows, how to obtain the current system time that ignores the timezone?

Tags: php, windows

I have the next problem.  I have several PHP systems running in different Windows machine. Those systems use intensivelly the current time.

Right now, i configured php.ini and assigned it to a specific timezone. Also Windows is configure to the same timezone and everything works as expected.

However, in my country, the State decided to change the daylight saving time.  So, sometimes, the admin changes the windows timezone and left unchanged the php timezone, creating a discordance in the system. Other times, is windows who changes automatically the timezone.

Is there are any way, from PHP, to obtain the current system time that ignores the timezone?.

**update**:

```
function time_zone_fix($timeGiven = "H:i:s")
{
    $shell = new COM("WScript.Shell") or die("Requires Windows Scripting Host");
    $time_bias = -($shell->RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\TimeZoneInformation\\ActiveTimeBias")) / 60;
    $timestamp_bias = 60 * 60 * $time_bias;
    return gmdate($timeGiven, strtotime($timestamp_bias . " seconds"));
}
```

gives the current date and time no matter what timezone/dsl is specified.
However, creating a new COM inteface is anything but efficient.

Comment: What is your issue? Are you installing the right time-zone data for PHP and do you keep that data up to date? And about which country do you speak? And the "timezone" you're looking for might be `UTC`. You can specify that in PHP with the ini setting.

Comment: The problem is it is not a single server but several ones with different configuration.   I can put the "right" timezone in php.ini but it will fail because the daylight saving time . Some machines changes the daylight saving time automatically while other changes the zone to do that. The timezone is between -4GMT and -3GMT (and i some cases, it worked with -5GMT).  Some machines changes the daylight saving time automatically while other the admin changes the GMT manually.

Comment: Just refer to UTC. An admin can not change UTC time, it's the fixed point in time. The time-zones and the daylight saving times are just describing what we view on the clock. UTC instead is the global coordinated time, so always the same (at least for us humans across the globe ;)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

changing the [format](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) to whatever you need. It returns the "timezone-less date-and-time". The `gm` stands for Greenwich Mean, as in [GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMT) (Greenwich Mean Time). GMT has been superseded by [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (Universal Time, Coordinated), so the function should really be called `utcdate()`...

But the most portable representation of time is the [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), i.e., the number of seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, ignoring leap seconds:

```
time();
```

The value of [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) is also the default value for the second parameter of [`gmdate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php).

BTW, a [leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) is scheduled for 2012-06-30 23:59:60

Note: In case you are asking for a way to get the time at a certain timezone but without the daylight saving time correction, you can do this:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 3600 * $h);
```

where `$h` is the offset in hours from UTC (a negative number in America), or, in case the offset is not a full number of hours:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 60 * $m);
```

where `$m` is the offset in minutes from UTC (e.g., 330 for IST, India Standard Time). A Unix timestamp with an added timezone offset doesn't make any sense by itself, though!

Last but not least, don't forget to synchronize your systems by means of [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), the Network Time Protocol.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Manual List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php):

> ... Here you'll find the complete list of timezones supported by PHP, which are meant to be used with e.g. `date_default_timezone_set()`. ...

And then this one: `UTC` (from this [sub-page](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php))

Answer (score 1):

PHP in Windows, how to obtain the current system time that ignores the timezone?
I have the next problem. I have several PHP systems running in different Windows machine. Those systems use intensivelly the current time.